# PHP cleanup function unable to remove &#39; (html_entity_decode not working ?)

Tags: php

I am using following cleanup function before inserting it to the db, however i see that

html characters like

```
&#39;
```

still remains in the db ? any reason why ? function is

```
$data = " &#39;hkh khj  &#39; ";

echo safe($data);;

function safe($data){
    $data = htmlspecialchars_decode($data);
    $data = html_entity_decode($data);
    //$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

```
$data = html_entity_decode($data ,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```